MoviePy not writing wav file in Docker container
I'm programming a video translation API, and I need Docker to do that. I've ran the API on my local Windows machine, and it works. I need to write down the audio from the mp4 to transcribe it into text.
It already works flawlessly on Windows, but it seems MoviePy isn't writing the file, and the class where that happens exits right away. I don't understand why.
This is the code, just in case:
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
from moviepy.editor import AudioFileClip
from scipy.io import wavfile
from noisereduce import reduce_noise
import numpy as np

class split():

    def __init__(self, path, id, video):
        self.completed = False
        self.id = id
        self.video = video
        self.path = path
        self.separar()

    def separar(self):
        try:
            print("......Separating video and audio......")
            # Cargar video
            video_editor = VideoFileClip(self.video)
            length = video_editor.duration
            # Separar parte audio
            audio_editor = video_editor.audio.subclip(0, length)
            # Guardar parte audio como fichero
            audiopath = f'{self.path}/{self.id}_audio.wav'
            audio_editor.write_audiofile(audiopath, codec="pcm_s16le")
            print("IT WORKED YIPPIII")
            # Cerrar recursos
            video_editor.close()
            audio_editor.close()
            # Reducir ruido
            self.reducir_ruido()
            self.completed = True
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error occurred during audio splitting:", str(e))
            self.completed = False
        except Error as error:
            print("Error ocurred:", str(e))
            self.completed = False

    def reducir_ruido(self):
        try:
            print("......Reducing noise......")
            # Cargar los datos de audio del archivo guardado
            rate, data = wavfile.read(f'{self.path}/{self.id}_audio.wav')
            orig_shape = data.shape
            data = np.reshape(data, (2, -1))
            # Realizar reducción de ruido
            reduced_noise = reduce_noise(

I tried changing the codec, I tried doing a -v when startin the container, I tried "falsifying" a clip making a clip that goes from 0 to video_length... and maybe more stuff I don't remember.

Could you provide your dockerfile? or at least indicate what the base image is?

Did you actually check if the file exists inside the container?
